# Javascript in a wordpress page

Tags: javascript

I have this code, but when I call it in the html, it does not do anything in wordpress.
How can I fix this> Thanks.

```
<script language="javascript">
var l1OK_WC = false;
var l2OK_WC = false;
function share()
{
   alert('yo');
}
function getIt_wc()
{
   if(l1OK_WC)
      window.open('http://google.ca','_self');

   if(!l1OK_WC)
      alert("Message 1");
   else if(!l2OK_WC)
      alert("Message 2");
}
</script>
```

And this in the html.

```
<a class="Style3" href="javascript:getIt_wc();"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/XJy0nEq.png" /></a>
```

When I click the button, no message appears. This script works fine in blogger or html sites, but not on wordpress. I am doing this on a wordpress page.

Thank you.

Comment: On a Wordpress site, as in you're using the CMS, or as in you have a blog hosted on Wordpress. And it's really bad form to use javascript in the href like that.

Comment: Using own domain with wp installed

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

HTML

```
<a class="Style3" id="my_button" ><img src="http://i.imgur.com/XJy0nEq.png"/></a>
```

Javascript

```
myLink = document.getElementById('my_button');
myLink.onclick = wc;

function wc(){
   if(l1OK_WC)
      window.open('http://google.ca','_self');

   if(!l1OK_WC)
      alert("Message 1");
   else if(!l2OK_WC)
      alert("Message 2");
}
```

Comment: Tried that but the button is not clickable.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `a` tag at all. Just use `onclick` on the image and remove the `a` tag:

```
<img class="Style3" src="http://i.imgur.com/XJy0nEq.png" onclick="getIt_wc()" />
```

To let people know it's clickable, in your stylesheet, add the `cursor` style to `Style3`:

```
.Style3 {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```